# `make` not linking locally installed library automatically (CS50x's cs50.h)

Tags: makefile, compiler-errors, compilation, gnu-make, cs50

I am trying to replicate [CS50x's](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50) sandbox on my Gentoo system, but I am getting this kind of error when running `make`

```
% make price
cc     price.c   -o price
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /tmp/cc9TASaL.o: in function `main':
price.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `get_float'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<builtin>: price] Error 1
```

For reference, this is the source file:

```
% cat price.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    float price = get_float("What's the price?\n");
    printf("Your total is %.2f (VAT included)\n", price * 1.22);
}
```

I have manually installed libcs50 on my system:

```
# ldconfig -p | grep cs50 
libcs50.so.10 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib64/libcs50.so.10
libcs50.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib64/libcs50.so
```

And when I compile the file with

```
% gcc -lcs50 price.c -o price
```

I am getting no errors.
Have I configured something wrong on my system, or have I misunderstood how `make` works?
After watching the lecture, I was under the impression that `make` would "automagically" add the `-lcs50` parameter.

Thanks!

**SOLUTION**
Set `CC`, `CFLAGS` and `LDLIBS` according to these instructions: https://cs50.readthedocs.io/libraries/cs50/c/ .
All the "automagical" stuff in the lecture videos is possible thanks to those environment variables.

Comment: How would it know how to "magically" add some random library?  (i.e., no, it won't do that).

Comment: I thought it'd add it. since I have installed the library in my system, and I have called it with `#include <cs50.h>` .
At this point, I think the instructor must have configured something extra in his sandbox, because he ran `make` without a Makefile or further arguments, and it compiled fine.
I am wondering if there is a commonly used way to replicate that?

Comment: You probably have at least 1,000 different libraries installed on your system for different reasons (a quick review shows 1,400 `lib*` packages installed on mine); it would definitely be incorrect for make to simply add them all to every link line.  As for the `#include`, first make doesn't parse your source code at all, and second there's no way it could reliably map an include file name to a library: there's no reason they will or should have the same name; many do not.

Comment: As for how your instructor did this, if he truly did not have a makefile then he must have had an environment variable set, something like `export LDLIBS='-lcs50'` in his shell setup file (`~/.bashrc`).  Are you _sure_ he didn't have a makefile?  That would certainly be unusual.  Keeping that in the environment is not a great idea because it applies to any make you run.

Comment: the mistake is the in the makefile, you've forgotten to link the library there. Could you post the makefile?

Comment: also, I can assure you - the CS50 instructor definitely had a makefile in the current directory (and a valid one) before running `make`.

Comment: Mystery solved! Thank you for your insights!
All the "automagical" stuff that was happening was due to a custom configuration of the sandbox he's running / providing to the students. For future reference, `echo $LDLIBS` returns `-lcrypt -lcs50 -lm` and `make price` returns `clang -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    price.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o price` when run from the sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Make has a built-in rule that can build an executable from a single `.c` file:

```perl
%: %.c
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
    $(LINK.c) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

That way you don't have to write a Makefile for most simple tasks like this one.
You can find it using `make -p | grep -C 3 '%: %.c\b'`.

The built-in variable `LINK.C` evaluates to:

```
LINK.c = $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH)
```

Seeing your last comment, all you have to do it call make while overriding the right variables:

```bash
make price CC=clang CFLAGS="-fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow" LDLIBS="-lcrypt -lcs50 -lm"
```